# Install Ubuntu 12.04 bootloader issues

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, bootloader

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 over Windows 7 using a USB drive. However, I am not able to install it. Installation breaks saying that "bootloader cannot be installed on 
this device." In the details section, I see the ubiquity message saying that it can't read the partition from dev/sda. I've tried various things, boot-repair one among them (http://paste.ubuntu.com/6056191/), but no luck. What am I exactly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it by disabling RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with clean disks with no partition table on it or did you reuse the disks. This can be the reason why your system won't boot. Guess how I know.

First clean your disks with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/yourdev bs=512 count=1
```

replace yourdev with the device name of your disks

Then install Ubuntu again. It will then install new gpt partition tables. You only need a swap and a boot partition in raid ofcourse.

Don't forget to adjust your uefi settings in the bios.